# Can I generate a key-pair in NodeJS, encrypt data in PHP using the public key, and decrypt in NodeJS?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

**Requirements:**

Essentially I have a series of devices (running `NodeJS`) that need to maintain their own unique private and public keys. They communicate with a centralized server in `PHP` by pulling content.

When a new device starts up, I would like it to generate a private and public key and send only the public key to the PHP server to be stored.

When a device runs a `GET` request on the PHP server, the server should use the public key it was provided to encrypt the data.

When the device receives this response, it should be able to use the private key to decrypt this data.

**Currently:**

I am currently generating a private and public key pair using [keypair](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keypair). I send the public key to the PHP server to be stored and associated with the unique device.

I encrypt the data on the PHP server using [EasyRSA](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA):

```
$message = "Decrypt me if you can";
$publicKey = new PublicKey($storedPublicKey);
$encrypted = EasyRSA::encrypt($message, $publicKey);
return $encrypted;
```

With this encrypted string being returned to the `NodeJS` app, I then try to decrypt it using [NodeRSA](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) (where `response` is the string response from the PHP server):

```
const key = new NodeRSA(storedPrivateKey)
const result = key.decrypt(response)
```

However it errors out with:

`Error during decryption (probably incorrect key).`

I believe I am missing something fundamental here, but am unsure on what that may be. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*EasyRSA* and *NodeRSA* aren't compatible.

*EasyRSA* is a wrapper for the [*PHP Secure Communications Library*](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/tree/2.0) (*phpseclib*). It's not a pure RSA encryption, but a [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem): RSA is used for asymmetric encryption and [*defuse/php-encryption*](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) for symmetric encryption. *EasyRSA* is described in more detail [here](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA#what-does-it-do-under-the-hood), *defuse/php-encryption* uses AES-256-CTR in its core and is described [here](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/CryptoDetails.md). The message to the recipient contains among other things the secret encrypted with the public RSA key and the plaintext encrypted with the symmetric key, where each component is Base64-encoded and all components are concatenated, separated by a `$`. Details can be found in the `encrypt`-method of the [`EasyRSA`](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA/blob/master/src/EasyRSA.php)-class. An example is:

```
EzR2$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$3vUCABOzsE0AWMMPy+EWtmAQheAq5oYVfOF7TapT1LoFn72UHbYNjpD2LgG7w6ZCQjRtLFzFZc17Ntme/LvWK97cV1+mOIpk+j6V6WHZRbwb36iBTGhACZUFTMPiSLPfTXJRu+tQkwi8$2f933da952b7c683
```

Such a message can't be decrypted directly by *NodeRSA* because *NodeRSA* expects a pure RSA message. In principle the decryption is possible, but would have to be done manually on the NodeJS side with probably relatively high effort (the main tasks would essentially include the RSA decryption of the secret, the derivation of the symmetric key from that secret, and finally the AES decryption). Since *NodeRSA* only covers the RSA part, the remaining parts require additional libraries or custom code on the NodeJS side.

Note that the *EasyRSA* page, section [*Important*](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA#important) warns of a possibly insufficient security.